# Save quotes in Bing Translator

Tags: bing, translation

If you enter this link:

```
https://www.bing.com/translator/?to=en&text=test"this,and that
```

You'll see the comma and space get delivered fine, but the quotes turn to **\x22**.

Is there anything that can bypass this linking limitation?

Some attempts:

```
1. https://www.bing.com/translator/?to=en&text=test%22this,and that (i.e. %22) => test\x22this

2. https://www.bing.com/translator/?to=en&text=test\"this,and that (i.e. escaping) => test\x5c\x22this

3. https://www.bing.com/translator/?to=en&text=test&quot;this,and that (i.e. &quot;) => test
(anything afterwards get deleted)
```

BTW, just for comparison, Bing has no problem with %2C (comma) and %20 (space):

```
https://www.bing.com/translator/?to=en&text=test"this%2Cand%20that
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of late 2019, it seems to be fixed!